# Trouble completing the Trailhead Challenge in Playground due to namespace prefix issue

Tags: trailhead, namespace

I use Playgrounds for completing my Trailhead challenges, but now I keep running into an error. the common decision is to create a fresh Playground so that namespace prefix was disabled.

the issue is that whenever I try to generate a fresh Playground it has already the namespace prefix enabled. what are other options for completing my challenges?

Comment: Create and link a developer org with your trailhead and complete the trail, Now I am not sure about if developer org already has the namespace prefix enabled or not, you can check and try.

Comment: @NightGuy thanks a lot, that helped!